# paintContent method not in Vaadin 7

Tags: migration, vaadin, paint, vaadin7, repaint

Our project has an add-on which has classes extend from CustomComponent & AbstractComponent and they override the method

```
public void paintContent(PaintTarget target) throws PaintException {    
        super.paintContent(target);
}
```

and this method does not seem to be in Vaadin 7 anymore.
What should we use in order to paint / repaint ?

Comment: Which add-ons are that?

Comment: Have a look at this wiki entry https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Migrating+from+Vaadin+6+to+Vaadin+7